# jquery inside angular function needs double click to invoke

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I just used a jquery inside a angular function and trying to invoke by ng-click. It works properly but always I need to second click on button to invoke the function

It is my function calling statement

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary showRest" id="btnShow" ng-click="loadHotels()">Show Restaurants</button>
```

It is my angular function which calls a service and if success it scrolls to a div

```js
$scope.loadHotels = function() {
  $scope.setPlace();
  if (p != null) {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/fudline/access/hotels/loadhotelsfromplace',
        data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike({
          place: p
        }),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
      })
      .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.hotels = data;
        $(".showRest").click(function() {
          $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: $(".hotels").offset().top
            },
            'slow');
        });
      }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        //
      });
  }


}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary showRest" id="btnShow" ng-click="loadHotels()">Show Restaurants</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

It is the section to go...

```
<div class="container text-center hotels">    
   <h3>Trending Restaurants</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: why do you need another click on success for the same element?

Comment: You don't need an event handler to invoke a method on success callback. Just remove the event handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding click event handler in the `success` callback thus its not working on first click.

You don't need event handler, get rid of it.

```
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.hotels = data;
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".hotels").offset().top
    }, 'slow');
})
```